# Gaming grants - pre-orders and electronic reciepts

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

A successful grant applicant is required to send a copy of an electronic receipt.

I have pre-ordered a game and I believe that (at least with Amazon), the money does not get taken out of my account until the item has been dispatched, so my original pre-order email isn't technically a receipt:

> Please note that for items ordered from Amazon.co.uk this e-mail is only an acknowledgement of receipt of your order and your contract to purchase these items is not complete until we send you an e-mail notifying you that the items have been dispatched to you.

Will I have to wait until I have received the receipt after the item has been dispatched?

If not and I can just send the first pre-order acknowledgement email, it feels like this could potentially be abused.

Comment: Can you cancel the preorder?

Comment: @badp I could indeed

Comment: Then it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait until you get an actual receipt of the purchase.

Comment: FYI the pre-order email from Amazon very much looks like a receipt.